# rust linking fails with aarch64-linux-android-clang, cannot find -lpython3.6m

Tags: python-3.x, rust, android-ndk, kivy, pyo3

So, to give a bit of context: I want to use a foreign (rust) library with python Kivy application for experimental self-educational purposes. I wasn't sure where to start since I never was too deep in compilation process so I decided to try using python-for-android recepies for foreign modules. After failing a couple of times, I thought about using a try-except in my python file on imports and then add android-compatible rust module into the APK. I don't know if it even will work but so far I have a problem compiling my rust lib for android, since it seems to miss some python related library, which is probably cuz of me using pyo3. I'm not sure how exactly should I solve this problem since it's my first time compiling something for android on Linux (particularly Ubuntu).

If someone could tell me how to fix the linking process I would really appreciate, below are the logs:
https://pastebin.pl/view/3d6a69ac
Also if you know how to achieve my goal better way please mention it as well.